# Heat Conduction in Deformed Solids

Tags: thermal-conductivity, phonons, solid-mechanics

I am working on a model for isotropic elastic solids and have to make a decision about **whether heat conduction should be isotropic in the reference or deformed configuration**.

I have spoken to two physicists about it and would like to know if anyone has a definite answer as to what is more physical.  As a basic minimal example, consider a cylindrical bar in a tension test.

- If heat conduction is based on the reference consideration then the after loading the bar it would be thinner in across its axis of symmetry, then the rate of heat diffusion across the bar would be identical regardless of how (elastically) deformed it were.
- On the other hand, if heat conduction is a 'spatial' phenomenon, we would find that heat diffusion from one side of the body to the other would be faster after tension.

What I/we have uncovered so far is :

- for plastic deformation it would be clear that the spatial configuration would be the physical one for heat conduction to occur.
- if we consider crystalline solids or poly-crystalline solids it seems that in elastic deformation the lattice structure might indeed continue to dictate heat conduction if phonons are somehow restrained by the deformation
- on the other hand, it seems the crystal oscillation amplitude is small compared with the gap between atoms, so it seems plausible in that case for the heat conduction to be unaffected or less affected by deformation.
- in metals heat conduction is largely associated with free electrons which should not be so sensitive to lattice deformations

I am curious if there is any testing data for this. I haven't been able to uncover any, but the search terms I used correspond to a lot of other research areas.

I also wonder what might be the case for polymer-based materials.

If I take the information I think I have uncovered I would say that for materials at moderate temperatures where the lattice oscillations are much smaller than the lattice parameter, or in metals, a spatially determined heat conduction model is justified.

I found this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234225/how-do-free-electrons-conduct-heat-in-a-metal) but it doesn't give me quite what I need here.

Comment: "*I also wonder what might be the case for polymer-based materials.*" Liu and Yang's "[Tuning the thermal conductivity of polymers with mechanical strains](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.81.174122)" could be a useful point to enter the literature.

Comment: Thermal conduction in metals at room temperature is mostly a phonon phenomena. In either event, grain boundaries and dislocation tangles are going to scatter both electrons and phonons, reducing thermal (and electrical) conductivity. Alloying generally does not help (thermal conductivity of stainless steel is about a third that of cast iron).

Comment: @JonCuster What are you basing your first sentence on? A [recent theoretical study of about 20 metals](https://engineering.purdue.edu/NANOENERGY/publications/Tong_PRB_2019.pdf) estimated a phonon (vs. charge carrier) contribution to thermal conduction at room temperature of only 2-40%. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, and perhaps you mean that even thermal conduction via charge carriers involves scattering from phonons.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Interesting @Chemomechanics that both studies were theoretical.  The first would be so easy to test. Also a shame that ordinary steels aren't considered in the latter.

Comment: @JonCuster, would be great to get a reference for that statement.  In your opinion what would be the implication for heat conductivity under deformation?

Comment: Is it true that the oscillations of the lattice are very small in comparison to the lattice parameter?

Comment: It's true that most work in this area remains theoretical, as the effect isn't that well understood and is often right around the noise floor. I would try looking at [who cited Bhowmick and Shenoy's broad survey](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=10922216941960452707) to find recent experimental work.

Comment: You mean in the area of phonon vs electron transport right? Surely someone must have tested how deformation impacts heat conduction. The [first of the papers](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.81.245318) in that list of yours cites Ross et al. as having comfirmed that thermal conductivity of semi-conductors increases under pressure.

Comment: OK skimmed through that paper by Ross. It covers ionic, molecular, semi-conductor and metallic crystalline solids.  There is a pressure effect. In metals pressure increases conductivity, but it is not clear how well they control for shape change. @JonCuster he writes "Metals differ from the materials  discussed in the previous subsections principally in that heat is transported mainly by electrons. "